# How do I geocode multiple fields?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps

I am trying to create a form that will geocode a google map. I have the basic code from the map API, but it only works with one field: 'address'.

Instead of using 'getElementByID', I am using 'getElementByClassName' so that it might use data from any of the fields I have set up.

That said, it isn't working. Am I going in the right direction by using a class instead of an ID?

Below is the code that I;m working with. API-KEY omitted.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.861933, -83.067746);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  address += " "+document.getElementById('street_add').value;
  address += " "+document.getElementById('city').value;
  address += " "+document.getElementById('state').value;
  address += " "+document.getElementById('postcode').value;
  address += " "+document.getElementById('country').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <form action="" name="" method="post">
         <input id="address" type="hidden" value="">
         <input id="street_add" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
         <input id="city" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
         <input id="state" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
         <input id="postcode" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
         <input id="country" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
         <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
       </form>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:40%;top:30px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no `getElementByClassName`, it's `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geocoder takes a single string representing an address.  You are currently not creating that, you are passing it an undefined value (there is no getElementByClassName, it is [getElementsByClassName](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_using.asp) and returns an array of HTML elements)

combine the separate values into a single string:

```
var address = document.getElementById('street_add').value;
address += " "+document.getElementById('city').value;
address += " "+document.getElementById('state').value;
address += " "+document.getElementById('postcode').value;
address += " "+document.getElementById('country').value;
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_geocoderCombineAddressElements.html)

Comment: I modified the code to combine the variables (see above) Also, I added a hidden field in the form with the id of 'address'. Seems to be working fine now.